# $A\setminus A'$ Dynkin System

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following problem:

Let $D$ be a Dynkin System and $A,A' \in D$ with $A'\subseteq D$, show that then also $A\setminus A' \in D$

my first question: Is there a typo from my teacher? should it be $A'\subseteq A$ ? I don't think $A'\subseteq D$ makes even sense, because an Element can not be a subset at the same time.

---

After beeing sure that there is a typo I'll try to proof the corrected problem ( for $A' \subseteq A$) :

$A\setminus A'= A\cap A'^c=A\cap (A'^c \cup A^c)= A\cap (A' \cap A)^c = (A^c \cup (A' \cap A))^c $

Now i can argue that $A^c \in D $ (because of $A\in D$)

But what about $A'\cap A$? Does $A'\subseteq A$ ensures me $A'\cap A \in D$?

Comment: Yes, there is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if $A$ and $A'$ are in $D$, and $A' \subset A$, we clearly have that $A \cap A' = A'$. So, $A' \cap A \in D$.

Comment: the moment when you feel totally blind ... ok that is really obvious. Thank You!

Comment: No problem. Do you mind accepting my answer if it solved your issue?